# How to contain this column within my box in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-column, flutter-responsive-layout

I am learning Flutter and am trying to develop a login screen. Specifically so far it's focused on just different tablets. The two I am simulating on as an example are an iPad and Pixel C tablet. I quickly drew a paint representation as I'm using a different laptop to make my post atm.

The first pic is on the iPad, the second on the Pixel. If it isn't evident, the problem I'm having is the if I have a different screen dimension such as the Pixel C, the column has it's elements overflow.

[image: iPad example]

[image: Pixel example]

I'm thinking maybe I'm having a fundamental misunderstanding of the way I should be laying it out and was wondering if I can be pointed in the right direction.

My idea is I have a stack.

The first item is a white background that scales with the height and width. I retrieve using MediaQuery and do the appropriate scaling.

The second item is the Column with the icon, text, fields and buttons. Scaling width ways is fine but the height is the issue.

Some psuedo code

```
Stack(
    Center(
        Container(
                White box with sizing, border etc
        ))
    Center(
        Column(
            Login column elements
        ))
    )
```

I am guess what's happening is the column is growing from the center of the screen so just is expanding outwards, so that's why it won't fit properly at other sizes? What should I do to contain the column within the box? I've been at this for hours going nuts trying different things, and feel like it's probably something simple.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in that case, using `Stack` isn't good, try using `Column` wrapped in `Container` to make white box. Fill the `Column` childern with login widget

simply like this

```
Container(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(Icons.star),
                                    Text('Login'),
                                    TextFormField(),
                                    TextFormField(),
                                    ElevatedButton(
                                        onPressed: () {},
                                        child: Text('Button')),
                                    ElevatedButton(
                                        onPressed: () {}, child: Text('Button'))
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Yes I've attempted this way as well, and it's still possible for the column to overflow the bottom edge of the box if the height gets small enough. I'm thinking a better approach would be, is it possible to retrieve the height of the column and use that as the box height?

Comment: `Column` will not overflow except you set the height of `Container`. Maybe can you update your question by adding some code or screenshot to make it clear.

Comment: Sorry never responded. Yes, as I learned more about heights and what not, obviously cannot exceed the Container limitations. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not the good use case for `Stack`

Because the background container doesn't know the height of `login elements`

Try Using `Container` instead:

Code Structure:

```
Container
  |_Column
    |_ Login elements here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the column inside the white box container as its child